# Display the selected/active link in a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple html menu, when a menu item is clicked a class of `mg_cats_selected" is added to the anchor tag (which is the menu item).

I would like to copy the text value of the active/selected anchor tag and display it in another div on the page, but I would like to only display it once. When a new item link is clicked, I want to remove the old value from the separate div that I've created it and display the new value of the new selected menu item.

I hope that makes sense.

This is the HTML menu

```
<div id="mgf_165" class="mg_filter mg_new_filters">

    <a rel="163" id="163" class="mgf_id_163 mgf mg_cats_selected left_menu" href="javascript:void(0)">Bathrooms Sinks</a>

    <a id="164" rel="164" class="mgf_id_164  mgf  left_menu" href="javascript:void(0)">Bowed</a>

</div>
```

This is the jQuery and the div where I wanna display the text values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('test');
    jQuery("a.left_menu").click(function(){
         var txt = jQuery("a.left_menu").text();
         //$(this).attr('rel');
         jQuery("#category").append(txt);
    });
});
</script>

<div id="category">
</div>
```

At the moment when I click on, say, "Bowed", this displays in the div

> Bathrooms SinksBowed

And if I click again on "Bathroom Sinks", the same thing repeats

> Bathrooms SinksBowedBathrooms SinksBowed

How can I deal with that? And did I follow the correct logic here?

Comment: You are appending the text, which basically.. appends/adds the text to the DIV again.

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery('#category').text(txt)`?

Comment: @JohnKeyes I just tried that. Now it's only displaying `Bathrooms SinksBowed` once no matter how many times I click on the menu items. However, I would only like to get the active/selected item with `mg_cat_selected` class and not all of them at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently getting the text of all the menu items and then appending it to the `div`.

You need to get the text of the clicked menu item, and then set the content of the `div` to the text value of that menu item.

```
jQuery(this)     // the clicked menu item
jQuery('#category').text('VALUE')   // set the text content of the tag to VALUE
```

[Working solution on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/o78sh0ow/).

See [Inside the Event Handling Function](https://learn.jquery.com/events/inside-event-handling-function/) to learn more about `jQuery` event handling.

Comment: @Halnex you're welcome. I added a link to some decent documentation on jQuery event handling.